# Splitting up tensor

Tags: tensorflow

Let `T` be a tensor of shape `[n,f]`, which represents a batch. Now I want to slice `T` into `m` tensors along `axis=0`. The value of `m` depends on the current batch. I have another tensor `I` of shape `[m,2]` which stores pairs of indices which indicate where the slices should occur.

I am not really sure how to "iterate" over the indices to apply `tf.slice`. Any ideas?

Can this somehow be achieved using `tf.scan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for the [split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) function.

Comment: No, the slices are not of equal size. These sizes are specified in `I`.

Comment: @Christopher Why do you think that tf.split can only handle equal sizes?  `num_or_size_splits` can be both an integer or a tensor with the split sizes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. The problem now is that the value for `num` cannot be infered. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Christopher: how did you work around the fact that num cannot be inferred?

Comment: According to the `tf.split()` documentation: "This requires that num_split evenly divides value.shape[axis]."

Comment: The answer needs elaboration. A working example, for instance.